# Apple reject my app with Guideline 5.2.5 - Legal - Intellectual Property, what's wrong?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I send to review iMessage stickers with title "Cool emoji - Stickers for text"
& subtitle "Cute emojis for iMessage"

I got reject:

> Guideline 5.2.5 - Legal - Intellectual Property Your app does not
>   comply with the Guidelines for Using Apple's Trademarks and
>   Copyrights. Specifically, your app includes:
>
> - iMessage in the app name or subtitle in an inappropriate manner

I checked Guidelines for Using Apple's Trademarks and Copyrights and in document have point:

> 2. Compatibility: Developers may use Apple, Macintosh, iMac, or any other Apple word mark (but not the Apple Logo or other Apple-owned
>      graphic symbol/logo) in a referential phrase on packaging or
>      promotional/advertising materials to describe that the third party
>      product is compatible with the referenced Apple product or technology,
>      provided they comply with the following requirements.
>
> b. The Apple word mark is used in a referential phrase such as “runs
>   on,” “for use with,” “for,” or “compatible with.”

Then I have question - what's wrong with my subtitle if I use "for" before iMessage ?
And what I should do next - send again to review ?

Comment: Remove the subtitle and resubmit?

Comment: Stickers only work in iMessage, right? So by definition the subtitle is superfluous. I would suggest that you use the subtitle to describe the kind of stickers that you are offering. Don't bother arguing with Apple about decisions like that, you will always loose and waste your time, so just accept their decision. I know that it is probably not what you want to hear, but trust me.

Comment: @inexcitus Thanks for answered. I already have another few stickers successfully approved, where in title/subtitle have "for iMessage" text. I don't understand why it's reject this time.

Comment: Does not matter if you have other apps yourself or there are other apps on the store with that. Follow the rules and/or escalate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but for review team if title include "emojis for iMessage" it's reject with reason "iMessage in the app name or subtitle in an inappropriate manner"

But when I changed "emojis for iMessage" to "stickers for iMessage" it was approved.

I don't know whats wrong with word "emojis"

Comment: A little nitpick: the Plural of "Emoji" is "Emoji". It’s a Japanese word. The Japanese language lacks plurals like we have in English. Just like you don't say "sushis".